# Basic probability formulation

Tags: probability

I am trying to determine if my understanding of some basic random distributions is correct in regard to a certain question.

One of the questions asks ,

say we had a bowl with six marbles and two were green, four were red.

I want to find out about the random variable X, which indicates the probability that on the x  drawing ( one at a time without replacement) the first red marble is drawn.

To me this seemed like a case of geometric distribution; Because I was taught that this is a distribution used when we are looking for the probability our first success on an $x th$ trial.

I was taught it was $P[X=x]=pq^{x-1}$ where p is chance of success and q is the chance of failure ie $1-p$.

I guess I am basically wondering how I can answer this , like how can I choose the correct p and q?

But how could I do it in such a case, because do not p and q change depending on which drawing we are on?

Would the p and q I use in the formula just depend on the original chances, ie $p=\frac{4}{6}$ and $q=\frac{1}{3}$ or is there something I am missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geometric is when we are repeating an experiment, **independently**, until the first success. Here, as you observed, the probability of success varies. In this case you are dealing with the negative hypergeometric, a rather obscure distribution.

But the calculation is straightforward. The random variable $X$ takes on values $1$, $2$, or $3$.

We have $\Pr(X=1)=\frac{4}{6}$.

The event $X=2$ occurs if we get a green and then a red, The probability the first is green is $\frac{2}{6}$. Given the first is green, the probability the second is red is $\frac{4}{5}$. Thus $\Pr(X=2)=\frac{2}{6}\cdot \frac{4}{5}$.

We leave $\Pr(X=3)$ to you.

Comment: Hey thanks, yes I worked this out as such. But so would my function just be that defined piece wise?  and P(x=3)= would have to be 1

Comment: $\Pr(X=3)$ can be calculated in the same way as I did $\Pr(X=2)$. We get $\frac{2}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{4}{4}$. Alternately, $\Pr(X=3)=1-\Pr(X=1)-\Pr(X=2)$.

Comment: As to "piecewise", as opposed I imagine to a general formula, we can use the same sort of reasoning to develop a general formula for the case $r$ red, $g$ green.  But that general formula is of little practical value, and in a probability course one exposes students only to the most important formulas, there are already too many of these!

Comment: And it is not only the "original chances" $4/6$ and $2/6$ that matter, we need to know the actual numbers, or the original chances and the total number of balls. The situation for $4$ red and $2$ green is quite different from $8$ red and $4$ green, but the ratios are the same, $4/6=8/12$.